# hibernate criteria: select object from one table using another one

Tags: sql, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

First of all sorry if my question is't very well formulated.

I have simple object which is mapped to corresponding table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private long userId;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
        //getters and setters...
```

In my database I also have another table. There isn't any associated object with this table but it has column "USER_ID" - the same id as in the "USERS" table.

So the question is, how to select all USERs from the first table which have the same USER_ID as in the second table using Hibernate criteria. For example I have two Users with userId =1 and =2. In second table in column "USER_ID" I have only value "2". So I need only User with  userId =2 from the first table.

Comment: Impossible without SQL. HQL and Criteria queries only use mapped entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is classic example of FOREIGN_KEY relation but as u said u don't have Hibernating mapping Model for another table.It's better to use sql-query in your user mapping file 
Collect this query result in User object.

Something like this
<sql-query name="userwith">
<return alias="user" class="User"/>
SELECT 
       user.Name AS {user.name}
FROM USERS 
JOIN ANOTHER_TABLE another_table
    ON user.ID = another_table.USER_ID
</sql-query>